# Delete all inner doubles

Tags: modeling, cycles-render-engine, vertices

i just started with 3d modeling and i ran in to a problem. While modeling i didn't notice something triplified all my inner vertices. Is there a way to select all inner duplicated vertices of my original model and delete them, without scraping whole project.

Thank you in advance for any help :)

[image]

Comment: Have you tried "remove doubles?"

Comment: Well i did, it did nothing.

Comment: It'll be time consuming and there might be a better way, but you could go around the outside, selecting all the good faces, then Select > Inverse to select all the bad faces. If you can post the .blend file, maybe we can play with it and figure out a better way to select the bad faces.